# Cannot use pinvoke to send WM_CLOSE to a Windows Explorer window

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a C# application that uses the SendMessage pinvoke method to send a "close window" message (WM_CLOSE / 16) to various windows outside the application.  This works great, except when the window in question is a Windows Explorer window.  I do not get an exception, but the window does not close.

Here's the signature:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Is there a different message that I need to send to Windows Explorer windows?  Or an alternate way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

an alternative solution would be to use PostMessage win API call instead of SendMessage, below is an example which worked fine for me (I'm using winXP sp3):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
public static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE          = 0x0010;

...

    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("ExploreWClass", null);
    if (hWnd.ToInt32()!=0) PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

differences between PostMessage and SendMessage api call are described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301431.aspx

Comment: Fantastic! Great alternative to [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which only works on the same thread that created the targeted window in the first place.