# Won't let me delete a folder that I just moved a file out of?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, windows-explorer

Here's my problem: I just finished up an app which allows you to right-click on a file in Explorer and hit an option to open the app.  It then renames and moves that file out of the folder to a specific location, and then deletes the folder (empty or not).  This works *fine* when the files are loaded through the GUI, but the whole point of the explorer context menu is that the GUI never has to load, it's just a one-hit-wonder for single files.

However, when using the context menu, the folder doesn't delete and it throws an exception saying the folder is in use by another process.  The file still gets moved and all other files still get deleted.  Why is this happening?  Is there some way I can explicitly release the handle on the directory in order to make this work?

I'd show you the code but it's extremely basic (ie one line, Directory.Delete).  I've also tried using DirectoryInfo.Delete but that didn't help.  Like I say, it works fine from within the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in assuming that deleting from the GUI means that the folder is not currently open in explorer whereas when you delete using the context menu the folder is (obviously) open? If so, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/09/10087919.aspx) might have some insight into the problem. Also, here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694451/cannot-use-pinvoke-to-send-wm-close-to-a-windows-explorer-window) which asked how to close an explorer window. Might help.

"Windows NT family of operating systems keeps open a handle to the process's current directory."

Comment: Thank you Nick - my problem was 100% solved simply by using Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AnywhereOtherThanHere) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think whats happening is explorer is trying to delete the folder while the file is being copied or moved. What you need to do is create a seperate thread that moves or copies the file (or files) first, then when that thread completes, delete the folder.