# Getting a list of all applications

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to get the list of all the open applications. Specifically, if you open the task manager and go to the applications tab, that list.

I've tried using something like this:

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
        {
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append("Window title: " + p.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Like in a few examples I've found, but this doesn't pull all the applications for me. It's only grabbing about half the ones I can see in the task manager or that I know I have open. For example, this method doesn't pick up Notepad++ or Skype for some reason, but DOES pick up Google Chrome, Calculator, and Microsoft Word.

Does anyone know either why this isn't working correctly or how to do so?

Also, a friend suggested it might be a permissions issue, but I am running visual studio as administrator and it hasn't changed.

EDIT: The problem I'm getting is that most of the solutions I've been given just returns a list of ALL processes, which isn't what I want. I just want the open applications or windows, like the list that appears on the task manager. Not a list of every single process.

Also, I know there is bad code in here, including the empty catch block. This was a throwaway project just to figure out how this works in the first place.

Comment: likely because those apps don't have a main window title.

Comment: if you program has a Main Window Title you could do something like this Chris Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var proc in processes)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
        Console.WriteLine(proc.MainWindowTitle);
}
you could also use `WMI` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Are you even looking at the code you're copy-and-pasting?

Comment: And, *never* use a `try` with an empty `catch { }`. It will simply mask errors and make bugs impossible to find. It's like saying "I don't care if this works or not."

Comment: Chris I have found a working solution for you I just tested it and it gets those running processes on  the Application TAB see my updated post

Comment: Found what I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451246/get-the-list-of-opened-windows-c-sharp

Answer (score 12):

The code example [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows) appears to give what you're asking for.  Modified version:

```
public class DesktopWindow
{
    public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}

public class User32Helper
{
    public delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText",
        ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows",
        ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction,
        IntPtr lParam);

    public static List<DesktopWindow> GetDesktopWindows()
    {
        var collection = new List<DesktopWindow>();
        EnumDelegate filter = delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder(255);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, result, result.Capacity + 1);
            string title = result.ToString();

            var isVisible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) && IsWindowVisible(hWnd);

            collection.Add(new DesktopWindow { Handle = hWnd, Title = title, IsVisible = isVisible });

            return true;
        };

        EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, filter, IntPtr.Zero);
        return collection;
    }
}
```

With the above code, calling `User32Helper.GetDesktopWindows()` should give you a list of containing the Handle/Title for all open applications as well as whether or not they're visible.  Note that `true` is returned regardless of the window's visibility, as the item would still show up in the Applications list of Task Manager as the author was asking.

You could then use the corresponding Handle property from one of the items in the collection to do a number of other tasks using other [Window Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx) (such as [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) or [EndTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633492(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Works great. In case you are trying to close a specific window and not the whole application I recommend this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694451/cannot-use-pinvoke-to-send-wm-close-to-a-windows-explorer-window). DestroyWindow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only works from the same thread and CloseWindow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only minimizes the targeted window.

Comment: I tried this. But it worked only to a certain extent. Its still showing few Background applications such as News, Settings, Calculator, Netflix etc. which are not open at the moment. But Im able to see those processes in the "Background Processes" section of the Task Manager.
Is there any way to get the list of Applications that are displayed on the Taskbar or in the "Apps" section of the Task Manager.

Answer (score 2):

As Mathew noted its probably because they don't have main titles and thus your filtering them out. The below code gets all the processes running. You could then use `Process.ProcessName` to filter out the one you don't want. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx) is the documentation on using ProcessName.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processes)
{
   //Get whatever attribute for process
}
```

Comment: I guess the thing I'm confused about is that I don't know exactly what I want to filter, if that makes sense. I know I want all applications that are running, but how can I check that? Most of the things I've seen on this matter is that if an application has a window, it has a MainWindowTitle, so how would I get things like Notepad++ which apparently does not?

Comment: @ChrisBacon It still has a processname or processid, if its running!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this Chris

//UPDATED below will get you all the processes running in the Application Tab

```
Process[] myProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process P in myProcesses)
{
    if (P.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(P.ProcessName + ".exe");
        Console.WriteLine(" " + P.MainWindowTitle);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue with this solution is that it still just gives me every process running, which isn't what I want. I _only_ want processes _with windows_. Basically all I want is applications that I could see in the Applications tab of my task manager.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said it's because some applications (Notepad++ being one) don't have a MainWindowTitle, to counter this my code (as an example) looks like this:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process pro in processes)
{
    if (pro.MainWindowTitle != "")
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(pro.ProcessName + " - " + pro.MainWindowTitle);
    }
    else
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(pro.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue with this solution is that it still just gives me every process running, which isn't what I want. I only want processes with windows. Basically all I want is applications that I could see in the Applications tab of my task manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, for some reason, MainWindowTitle is null for some processes, so you are skipping those ones. Try this just for test:

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
     sb.Append("\r\n");
     sb.Append("Process Name: " + p.ProcessName);
     sb.Append("\r\n");
}
```

Maybe your try...catch is jumping some processes if it gets some error, so try without it also.

**UPDATE:**
Try this, it's ugly and take some processes that has no windows but maybe you can filter..

```
var proc = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "tasklist",
        Arguments = "/V",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.Start();
StreamReader sr = proc.StandardOutput;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @".{52}(\d+).{94}(.+)$");//157
    if (m.Success)
    {
        int session = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value);
        string title = m.Groups[2].Value.Trim();
        if (session == 1 && title != "N/A") sb.AppendLine(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried taking away the try/catch block, but it still ignores some windows. And the main issue is that I don't want every single process, I just want the ones with windows associated with them.

Comment: Chris, your code run in my computer, including Skype and Notepad++. What windows and framework versions are you using?